# How to set a transparent background in AO and other render passes?

Tags: eevee-render-engine

[image]

Hi and apologies if this question is addressed elsewhere - I've been googling and haven't yet found a solution, only other artists complaining about the same problem!

Is there a way to configure all passes except the beauty pass to have a transparent background? I'm using Eevee to output several passes and save them in OpenEXR multilayer format, for compositing in Photoshop.

I've ticked the 'transparent' checkbox in the film options, and enabled alpha in the OpenEXR add-on I'm using in Photoshop, but right now only the beauty pass is displaying a transparent background in my Photoshop layer stack. The AO and Normal passes have a black background, and the Depth and Shadow passes have a white background. I'd like all to be transparent if possible.

Here's my node setup. I tried adding a SetAlpha node to AO but I don't think I'm using it correctly. Any suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

By default, passes don't carry alpha, so you need to add it back from your render layer node.

What you need to do is, for each pass, add a Set alpha node just before file output's in socket.
In set alpha's image input, use whatever pass you need, and in its alpha you can use the render layer's alpha.

Then, to remove the alpha from the beauty pass, still use a Set alpha node, but in Replace Alpha mode and with the alpha input unplugged and set to 1.

It will look something like this:

[image: demo comp]